# How to use scripted web API code in to HTML documents

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to implement **speech recognition interface** in one of my HTML documents.

I have searched for it and found the below link.

https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html

But I don't know how to embed the interface code in to HTML document.

Can any one help me how to use it.

Comment: You don't: *"This specification was published by the Speech API Community Group. It is not a W3C Standard nor is it on the W3C Standards Track."*
The latest version of Google Chrome doesn't support it, and I doubt any other browser does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to record and print a speech in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23213380/how-to-record-and-print-a-speech-in-html)

Comment: @MikeW It is not a duplicate, because this question is asking specifically about the W3C speech API.

Answer (score 0):

What the formal W3C specifications call an interface is not what you usually think of when you work with an object-oriented language. The specifications describes what a *web-browser* needs to implement in its Javascript library to fulfill the specification. Unless you are developing your own web-browser, you don't implement anything. You just use the implementations provided by the web browsers.

As of now (April 2014) the W3C speech API you linked to is just an experimental recommendation. [The only browsers which supports it partially are Chrome and Safari](http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-speech). The experimental implementation prefixes all text-to-speech objects with `webkit`, so `SpeechRecognition` becomes `webkitSpeechRecognition`. Any other browser does not implement it at all at the moment, and it is not yet sure they will ever do. For that reason you should try to find a different solution for your problem.

When you still want to experiment with it, you can [find an example for the web speech API](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html) on Googles Chrome demos (the interesting parts start at line 288 of the sourcecode). But as I said, it isn't ready for any productive use.